# How to get the cummean of the last n rows before the last row using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, mean, cumulative-sum

If I have a data frame that I am going through using dplyr, how can I get the cummean of the last 2 rows *before* the last row?

For example...

```
 ------
   |value|
   -------
   | 1   |
   ------
   | 2   |
   -------
   | 3   |
   ------
   | 4   |
   -------
```

In this case, when the code goes through the value 4, I want the cummean to calculate (2+3)/2.

I am thinking something along the lines of this--

```
new_df -> df %>%
    summarise(
       roll_mean = cummean(value,-2)
    )
```

However I know this does not work

Comment: What is the expected output?  Did you meant `df %>% mutate(value2 = lead(cummean(value), 2))`

Comment: I want the output to be a new df that has the rolling means as calculated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using this data: `df <- data.frame(value = 1:4)`]

For two prior values, you could do it manually like so:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(roll_mean = (lag(value) + lag(value,2))/2)

#  value roll_mean
#1     1        NA
#2     2        NA
#3     3       1.5
#4     4       2.5
```

Or if the window might be larger, it could be easier to use `slider:slide_*`, a nice set of window functions. Here we ask for the mean for a window that starts two elements prior (`.before = 2`) and ends one element prior (`after = -1`).

```
df %>%
  mutate(roll_mean = slider::slide_dbl(value, mean, .before = 2, .after = -1))

#  value roll_mean
#1     1       NaN
#2     2       1.0
#3     3       1.5
#4     4       2.5
```

By default `slider` allows incomplete windows; if we want the same output we could use:

```
df %>%
  mutate(roll_mean = slider::slide_dbl(value, mean, .before = 2, .after = -1, .complete = TRUE))

#  value roll_mean
#1     1        NA
#2     2        NA
#3     3       1.5
#4     4       2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that what you mean is at each position calculate the mean of the prior two elements of `value`, use `rollapply` with a width of `list(-seq(2))` which means that at each point use the offsets -1 and -2, i.e. one and two positions earlier.  Replace 2 with n to get the mean of the prior n values as referred to in the subject.

```
library(dplyr, exclude = c("filter", "lag"))
library(zoo)

DF %>% mutate(mean = rollapply(value, list(-seq(2)), mean, fill = NA))
##   value mean
## 1     1   NA
## 2     2   NA
## 3     3  1.5
## 4     4  2.5
```

A variation is the following. Replace 3 with n+1 to get the mean of the prior n values as referred to in the subject.

```
DF %>% mutate(mean = (rollsumr(value, 3, fill = NA) - value) / 2)
```

### Note

Input in reproducible form:

```
DF <- data.frame(value = 1:4)
```